# segfault when reading last line of file using fgets()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I'm solving a coding problem for a Data Structures assignment, and one part of my solution keeps giving me a `segfault: 11` when reading the last line of a text file using fgets().

I've already searched around StackOverflow for some time now and can't find the same error I'm getting. I've tried many ways to solve the problem but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

```c
int main() {
    **S = func();
    free(S);
    return 0;
}

char** func() {
    FILE *fStrings = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (fStrings == NULL) printf("Error opening 'file.txt'\n")
    int length = fileLength("file.txt");  // This returns just the number of lines in a file, works as intended.
    char **strings = (char **)malloc(200 * length * sizeof(char));
    f(length, (char (*)[200])strings, *fStrings);
    // some code using the data modified by f()
    fclose(fStrings);
    return strings;
}

void f(int length, char strings[][200], FILE *fStrings) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);  // debug
        fgets(strings[i], 200, fStrings);  // Here's the problem
        printf("string = %s\n", strings[i]);  // debug
    }
}
```

The above code has 2 debug lines to see where exactly the error happens. The function is called with the correct parameters, where `length` is the amount of strings in the array, `strings` is an array of strings, and `fStrings` a file with said strings.

The `segfault` occurs when trying to read the last line of the text file. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Changed the code block to include a better version of my code, in case it makes it easier to understand. The correct libraries are included too.

Comment: Your pointer calculations won’t work. Why not use the arrays properly, like `strings[i]` as you do in the `printf` anyway? Where did you learn to do this, out of curiosity?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The pointer calculation is strange but why won't it work?

Comment: You need to show us how you call the function and how the parameters are defined and initialized.

Comment: @4386427 Because an array of arrays is not necessarily in contiguous memory. They can be anywhere so accessing past the end of one isn’t ok.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I think it is ...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen see https://ideone.com/I6Xli3

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {` ==> `for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {`

Comment: Your allocation is strange. You should allocate a 2D array instead of doing casts.

Comment: `**S = func();` is illegal code! Post your real code...

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem with your code is this line

```
for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
```

Due to `<=` it will loop "length + 1" times but you have only allocated memory for "length" times. Change it to:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
```

Your allocation is strange. You should allocate a 2D array using a pointer to a 1D array, i.e. like this:

```
char (*strings)[200] = malloc(length * sizeof *strings)
```

then you can do the call without any cast.

Also just noticed this line:

```
f(length, (char (*)[200])strings, *fStrings);
                                  ^
                                  notice
```

I don't think you want `*` in front of `fStrings` (it should not even compile with the `*`)

With the correct allocation (as described above) the call should be:

```
f(length, strings, fStrings);
```